# Illuminate\Mail\MailManager::getConfig(): Argument #1 ($name) must be of type string

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

When I try to config mail from livewire controller and send mail with foreach loop then show the error "Illuminate\Mail\MailManager::getConfig(): Argument #1 ($name) must be of type string, null given, called in /Users/msurubel/Web_Application_Projects/Lourent/Email_Marketing_App/main_app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailManager.php on line 107"

Controller Code

```php
$getAllSubscribers = subscribers::wheregroup_id($this->SelectingGroupInput)->get();
//Config SMTP
$getSMTPConfig = smtp_configs::whereref_id($this->SelectingSMTPConfigInput)->first();
$mailConfig = array(
    'mailer'     => $getSMTPConfig->mailler,
    'host'       => $getSMTPConfig->host,
    'port'       => $getSMTPConfig->port,
    'from'       => array('address' => $this->SendingFromEmail, 'name' => $this->SendingFromName),
    'encryption' => $getSMTPConfig->encryption,
    'username'   => $getSMTPConfig->username,
    'password'   => $getSMTPConfig->password,
);
Config::set('mail', $mailConfig);

foreach ($getAllSubscribers as $lists){
  $getSubscriberData = subscribers::whereid($lists->id)->first();

  $details = [
      'CompanyName' => $this->SendingFromName,
      'subject' => $this->SendingSubjectline,
      'MailBody' => "Hi, How are you.",
      'name' => "App",
  ];
  Mail::to("$getSubscriberData->email")->send(new BulkMail($details));
}
```

This my error view - https://flareapp.io/share/x7Xp90w7#F60

Comment: You're overwriting the Laravel configuration `mail` with a different structure: You're getting this error because this line does not exists anymore in the configuration after you replaced the config `mail` : https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/config/mail.php#L16 I suppose you want to overwrite `mail.mailers.smtp`

Comment: Also; `$getSMTPConfig->mailler,` should be `$getSMTPConfig->mailer,` I guess

Comment: $getSMTPConfig->mailler it's come from database, I write the row name mailler not mailer.

Comment: Can you talk me how I config customize mail setting from livewire controller?